# Angular GET Request Stuck in Cycle

Tags: angularjs, node.js, postgresql, express

I am trying to use angular to make a request to an api I made that retrieves and manipulates data in a Postgres database. I have two running copies of this website, one uses Mongo. The problem code below runs fine on the server using Mongo but for some reason the Postgres one is experiencing trouble. When I use a REST client to test the api, both versions work (Mongo and Postgres), leading me to believe the api is not the problem. However, my main page contains an angular controller that makes GET and POST requests to the api. Like I said, the only time this loop happens is on the server with Postgres.

Here is the controller in question:

```
(function() {

    var PostCtrl = function ($http, $scope, $log, $location) {

        $scope.getPosts = function() {
            $http.get("api/posts")
                .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.posts = response.data;
                });
        }

        $scope.addPost = function(title, content, image) {
            $http.post("api/posts", {title: title, content: content, image: image})
                .error(function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            //$scope.getPosts();
        }


        //$scope.getPosts();
    };

    app.controller("PostCtrl", ["$http", "$scope", "$log", "$location", PostCtrl]);

})();
```

Here is the page where I am using the controller:

```
extends partials/layout

block scripts
    script(src="app/controllers/PostCtrl.js")

block content
    div(ng-controller="PostCtrl")
        .row
            .col-xs-9
                #main
                    .row
                        .col-xs-12
                            form(class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="post(title, content, image)")
                                .form-group
                                    label(for="inputTitle" class="col-sm-2 control-label") Title
                                    .col-sm-10
                                        input(required type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTitle" placeholder="Title" ng-model="title")
                                .form-group
                                    label(for="inputContent" class="col-sm-2 control-label") Content
                                    .col-sm-10
                                        textarea(required class="form-control" id="inputContent" placeholder="Content" ng-model="content")
                                .form-group
                                    label(for="inputImg" class="col-sm-2 control-label") Image URL
                                    .col-sm-10
                                        input(required type="text" class="form-control" id="inputImg" placeholder="Image URL" ng-model="image")
                                .form-group
                                    .col-sm-offset-2.col-sm-10
                                        button(type="submit" class="btn btn-default") Post

                    .row
                        .col-xs-12
                            div(ng-repeat="post in getPosts()")
                                hr
                                .well
                                    h2 {{ post.title }}
                                    h4 {{ post.content }}
                                    img(src="{{ post.image }}")

            .col-xs-3
                .row
                    .col-xs-12
                        #sidebar
                            .well(style="height: 500px;")

block footer
    .row
        .col-xs-12
            hr
            .footer
                h4(class="copyright") Footer
```

Here is the API just in case:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var pg = require("pg");

var dbUrl = "postgres://usr:pwd@localhost:5432/vagablog";

// Middleware for all routes.
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("API request made.");
    next(); // Go to next routes, don't stop here
});

// Test route to ensure routing is working
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.json({
        message: "Hooray! Welcome to the API!"
    });
});

// On routes that end in /posts
router.route("/posts")

    // Get all posts. (Accessed at GET api/posts)
    .get(function(req, res) {

        // Connect to DB
        var client = new pg.Client(dbUrl);
        client.connect();
        console.log("Client connected to DB");

        // Select all from post table
        var query = client.query("select * from post");

        // Send response on failed query with error
        query.on("error", function(error) {
            res.send({
                status: "failed",
                reason: error
            });
        });

        // Add each row to result
        query.on("row", function(row, result) {
            result.addRow(row);
        });

        // Send response on successful query with results
        query.on("end", function(result) {
            client.end();
            res.send(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
        });

    })

    // Create post. (Accessed at POST api/posts)
    .post(function(req, res) {

        // Connect to DB
        var client = new pg.Client(dbUrl);
        client.connect();
        console.log("Client connected to DB");

        // Check if needed request body items are valid
        if(req.body.title !== undefined && req.body.content !== undefined) {

            // Perform insert query
            var query = client.query("insert into post (title,content) "+
            "values ('"+req.body.title+"','"+req.body.content+"')");

            // Send response on failed query
            query.on("error", function(error) {
                client.end();
                res.send({
                    status: "failed",
                    reason: error
                });
            });

            // Send response on successful query
            query.on("end", function(result) {
                client.end();
                res.send({
                    status: "success",
                    title: req.body.title,
                    content: req.body.content,
                    image: req.body.image
                });
            });

        // Send response if missing request body item
        } else {
            res.send({
                status: "failed",
                reason: "Could not find one or more of parameters: title, content, image"
            });
        }

    });

router.route("/posts/:post_id")

    // Get post. (Accessed at GET api/posts/:post_id)
    .get(function(req, res) {
        // TODO Get post
    })

    // Update post. (Accessed at PUT api/posts/:post_id)
    .put(function(req, res) {
        // TODO: Update post
    })

    // Delete post. (Accessed at DELETE api/posts/:post_id)
    .delete(function(req, res) {

        // Connect to DB
        var client = new pg.Client(dbUrl);
        client.connect();
        console.log("Client connected to DB");

        // Delete from post table where id is equal to :post_id
        var query = client.query("Delete from post Where id ="+req.params.post_id);

        // Send response on successful deletion with error
        query.on("end", function(result) {
            client.end();
            res.send({
                status: "success"
            });
        });

        // Send response on failed deletion with error
        query.on("error", function(error) {
            client.end();
            res.send({
                status: "failed",
                reason: error
            });
        });

    });

// TODO: Create api routes for table deletion/clearing/creation

module.exports = router;
```

Server output:

```
GET /api/posts 200 20.691 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 22.513 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 25.023 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 17.603 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 19.947 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 13.149 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 12.391 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 16.033 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 17.256 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 18.421 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 18.786 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 19.534 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 16.590 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 19.997 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 15.494 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 18.389 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 14.374 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 18.409 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 19.716 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 21.166 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 23.422 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 23.104 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 23.240 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 23.442 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 26.767 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 20.711 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 18.902 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 20.807 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 22.459 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 23.733 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 20.734 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 19.195 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 19.811 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 14.928 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 15.960 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 18.811 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 20.031 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 22.332 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 19.272 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 19.888 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 20.281 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 18.424 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 22.150 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 23.577 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 24.877 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 27.099 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 26.699 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 28.815 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 29.594 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 24.583 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 24.909 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 21.310 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 25.254 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 22.883 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 24.659 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 27.842 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 23.009 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 31.817 ms - 73
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
API request made.
Client connected to DB
GET /api/posts 200 22.164 ms - 73
GET /api/posts 200 25.102 ms - 73
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions will always re-run if Angular thinks there is a change in any of your models, or if anything happens that triggers a digest cycle (this might not be 100% correctly phrased, any input is appreciated here).

```
    $scope.getPosts = function() {
        $http.get("api/posts")
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.posts = response.data;
            });
    }

    $scope.addPost = function(title, content, image) {
        $http.post("api/posts", {title: title, content: content, image: image})
            .error(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        //$scope.getPosts();
    }
```

The above will always try to run when angular thinks there's a model change.

You should try

```
$scope.posts = [];

$http.get("api/posts").then(function (response) {
    $scope.posts = response.data;
});

$scope.addPost = function(title, content, image) {
    $http.post("api/posts", {title: title, content: content, image: image})
        .then(function (response) { 
                 //success
                 console.log(response.data); 
              }, 
              function (response) { 
                 //error
                  console.log(response.data);
              });
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to this stuff. In the problem code, where exactly does Angular think a model is being changed?

Comment: Angular will only execute scope functions during a digest cycle if they are being watched. If you aren't watching getPosts then this shouldn't be an issue